# Является ли предложение "Женщина должна быть женственной" тавтологией?

Tags: тавтология, риторика

Допустимо ли употребление фразы "Женственная женщина", "Женщина должна быть женственной", или это "масло масленое"?

Answer (score 3):

Тавтология, как и большинство стилистических ошибок, может быть средством художественной выразительности. Для этого повтор однокоренных слов должен быть стилистически мотивированным, а сами эти слова не должны быть семантически избыточными. Функция этого стилистического приема - акцентирование понятия, заключенного в повторяющейся корневой части.

Ср. у Цветаевой:

Два на миру у меня врага,

Два близнеца неразрывно-слитых:

Голод голодных - и сытость сытых.

А *женственная женщина* - это даже не стилистический прием, а просто точное выражение понятия. Женщина, как и мужчина, бывает женственной и мужественной. Так что такое словоупотребление вполне нормально.

Answer (score 2):

Как сказал Л.И. Брежнев, "экономика должна быть экономной". Все были просто потрясены эти средством художественной выразительности. Как просто, и как понятно!

Никто не отрицает, что женщина должна быть женственной, но подобные выражения в тексте уже не воспринимаются качестве стилистического приема или свежего художественного образа, а похожи на самую классическую тавтологию.